# my 'Select DISTINCT' is not working properly

Tags: php, html, mysql, distinct

I tried to populate my drop down menu with some values from the database.
After I use 'Select DISTINCT'it does not retrieve all the data in my data base.

Here is my php code

```
<?
   $sqlretrive = mysql_query("Select DISTINCT type from 
             tb_shuffle_table where status = 1 and user_id = $user_id");
   $rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqlretrive)
?>
```

and here is my html code

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="form-control" required >
      <option value="">Please Select Question Type</option>
      <? while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlretrive)){ ?>
      <option value="<?=$row['type']?>">
        <?=$row['type']?>
        </option>
      <? }?>
    </select></td>
```

{this is my database table}[1](http://i61.tinypic.com/1433xxi.jpg)

Comment: Show some sample data.

Comment: Define 'does not retrieve all the data'

Comment: please share your table structure.

Comment: my reputation is low. I cant post pictures yet.

Comment: let me explain a bit more . I have a list of 11111112222222233333444555555 in my 'type' field in the database. I want to populate this list in a drop down menu. At first, it shows all the list but after I use 'select DISTINCT', the drop down only shows '2345' ... it doesnt show '1'.

Comment: what it shows? what u want

Comment: i want it to show 12345 like it should show.

Comment: if it is showing 2345 then something is wrong with your data? check data. your script is fine

Comment: thanks. I will check my data again

Comment: this is my database table       :    http://i61.tinypic.com/1433xxi.jpg

Comment: check this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9df06/2 ...

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, using `select distinct type ...` if it does filter out `1` then it's simple to understand that the particular record(s) is not matching your provided `WHERE` condition as pointed below.

```
where status = 1 and user_id = $user_id
```

Comment: I have checked. Both of them matched. I wish I could show you my database

Comment: You can host an image at any site and post a link :)

Comment: it is the same user_id and status for all the records